# Post Viewmodel to controller using jQuery Ajax but model is null

Tags: jquery, ajax, null, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Student.cs

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }        
    public string Class { get; set; }
}

public class StudentViewModel
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public List<string> SelectedClass { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ClassList { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller StudentController

```
  public class StudentController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Student/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var student = new Student { 
            StudentId = 1, 
            StudentName = "Himen Suthar"                 };

        var classList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        classList.Add(new SelectListItem {Text  = "Std 8" ,Value = "1"});
        classList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Std 9", Value = "2" });
        classList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Std 10", Value = "3" });

        var viewModel = new StudentViewModel();
        viewModel.Student = student;
        viewModel.ClassList = classList;

        return View(viewModel);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(StudentViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 

        }


        var classList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        classList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Std 8", Value = "1" });
        classList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Std 9", Value = "2" });
        classList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Std 10", Value = "3" });



        model.ClassList = classList;

        return View(model);
    }

}
```

Index:

[image: Index.cshtml]

I have List box on index page, when I change list box value, than it will post model to the Controller, But I am getting null value for View model, but the Model State is valid. Please guide to do show.

ViewModel is null:

[image: ViewModel is null]

Answer (score 0):

For this you can refer this link for passing the value of model from controller to view ,so you can get data.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/786604/Passing-data-from-Controller-to-View-in-ASP-NET-MV

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with your json

What you provided would match this class def. Notice how Student is a collection. Also because of the enclosing '[',']' you actually have a List< StudentViewModel> coming into the post instead of a single StudentViewModel. You also will not be able to map classlist to a SelectListItem with that json.

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
}

public class ClassList
{
}

public class StudentViewModel 
{
    public List<Student> Student { get; set; }
    public string SelectedClass { get; set; }
    public List<ClassList> ClassList { get; set; }
}
```